# How to get google search Results (Zero click search) from google API (Programmable Search Engine)?

Tags: python, google-custom-search

when we search in google we get our extact answer without going into url or page. I want to get the same result from google api.

I do not get search result from API as I get results from browser.
I want to have the zero click results from API.
the results of browser of browser and API are different. the results and ranking of websites are also different.

example:
query: who is PM of UK?
browser: Boris Johnson
API result: This article is about the office. For the current holder, see Boris Johnson. For a list of British prime ministers, see List of prime ministers of the United\xa0...

reference:
https://cse.google.com/cse/all

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

programmable-search and google.com are two different things, it works on different algorithms.
for more details.
https://support.google.com/programmable-search/answer/70392